# Enum inside a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, enums

Let's say I have a class `Class`, which has an associated enum member `Enum`. The enum only makes sense in the context of this class, and therefore it is specified inside it. Then you can just call `Class::Enum::Something` from outside of the class, which is fine.

```
class Class
{
   public:
      enum class Enum : uchar
      {
          Something
      }
}
```

However, if the class `Class` is templated, you cannot do `Class::Enum::Something`, but you have to `Class<T>::Enum::Something` (or `Class<>::Enum::Something` if `T` has some default type).

```
template <typename T = double>
class Class
{
   public:
      enum class Enum : uchar
      {
          Something
      }
}
```

The `Enum` has to be the same for all `T`s, since it's just a simple enum, but the `T` always has to be specified anyway.

My question is - is there a clever way of avoiding this?

Comment: You could add your class declaration to a namespace, and then add the enum to the namespace rather than the class.

Comment: Minor point on terminology: you cannot "call" `Class::Enum::Something`. It's not a function.

Comment: The `Enum` is different in each template instantiation, despite having all the same names. If you want the same `Enum` you can't put it inside a template. One possibility would be to define it in a class and use that class as a base class for the template.

Answer (score 5):

It is essential to understand that the wrapped enum type is a *different* type for different specializations of `Class`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = double>
struct S
{
      enum class E : int { a };
};

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<S<>::E, S<int>::E>);  // !!!
```

It seems like you want this to actually be the same type, in which case you could break it out into a separate class and use private implementation inheritance to expose it via the class template specializations:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
struct Base {
    enum class E : int { a };
};
}  // namespace detail;

template <typename T = double>
struct S : private detail::Base
{
    using Base::E;    
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<S<>::E, S<int>::E>); // OK
```

However *if* you are set on supplying this enum as a member (alias declaration above) of the various class template specializations, you will need to qualify which specialization you refer to.

```
S<>::E;
S<int>::E;
```

The root problem you seem to want to solve is *scoping*, in which case you may use a namespace instead of class to wrap the associated enum:

```
namespace my_lib {

template <typename T = double>
struct S {};

enum class E : int { a };

}  // namespace my_lib
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. I am aware that the wrapped enums are different types, and exactly as you said, the issue I want to solve is scoping. I guess I will have to resort to the namespace solution, even though that forces me to de-couple the enum from the class and "expose" the enum to everything else inside the same namespace.

Comment: @Jixxy don't think java. Not everything that belongs to a class must be defined inside the class. If you accept that, then defining `Enum` outside of `Class` is no worse than having it nested inside

Answer (score 1):

Often it is more convenient to move everything that does not depend on the tempalte argument to a non-template base class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
   public:
      enum class Enum
      {
          Something
      };

};

template <typename T = double>
class Class : public Base
{
};

int main() {
    std::cout << (Class<>::Enum::Something == Class<int>::Enum::Something);
}
```

Comment: Yes, or `Base::Enum::Something` instead of `Class<T>::Enum::Something`. Too bad the standard doesn't allow `Class::Enum::Something` in this case when the enum is inside a non-templated base class, and thus cannot possibly depend on `T`.

Comment: @Jixxy it does depend on `T`. Also in my code. You can for example write a specialization `Class<int>` that does not inherit from `Base`, then there is no `Class<int>::Enum`. In some sense, everything in the template depends on `T`

Comment: @Jixxy -- a specialization of `Class` doesn't have to have that base class, so the presence of `Base::Enum::Something` does, in theory, depend on `T`. `template <> class Class<int> {};` is a valid specialization.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh ok I've never seen that, thanks

Comment: @Jixxy Note a subtle different between this approach and the very similar one of mine: as you use public inheritance here, it is publically visible that "Class is a Base". As we use implementation inheritance here, we typically _don't_ want that, particularly as the inheritance offers no polymorphic behaviour for "Class is a Base". That we are using `Base` for implementation inheritance is an _implementation technique_, and something we should hide from clients. Imo this answer offers a worse alternative to the technique that was already presented in my own answer.